# How to handle WebUI.click() and WebUI.setText() built in keywords using "XPATH"

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, katalon-studio

I am unable to click on an object/ unable to set a text in login box using xpath

```
WebUI.setText(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"edit-name\"]")), username)
WebUI.setText(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"edit-pass\"]")), password)
WebUI.click(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"user-login\"]/div/div/button")))
```

Text should be entered in to the login boxes
click on Go button!

Answer (score 1):

WebUI object works with TestObject, not the WebElement of selenium. You could either use manual mode or scripting mode to create the test script.

Comment: What is the difference/connection between TestObject and WebElement?

Comment: TestObject is the object in Katalon and we can use it like findTestObject. WebElement is from Selenium. We need to use selenium command for it.

Comment: So, it is just a formal difference - Katalon uses one, and Selenium the other? But, it is the same thing, basically.

Answer (score 1):

First, you define test objects like this:

```
TestObject editName = new TestObject().addProperty('xpath', ConditionType.EQUALS, '//[@id=\"edit-name\"]')
TestObject editPass = new TestObject().addProperty('xpath', ConditionType.EQUALS, '//[@id=\"edit-pass\"]')
TestObject userLogin = new TestObject().addProperty('xpath', ConditionType.EQUALS, '//*[@id=\"user-login\"]/div/div/button')
```

And then use them in your script

```
WebUI.setText(editName, username) 
WebUI.setText(editPass, password) 
WebUI.click(userLogin)
```

Note: I guess username and password used here are variable names, otherwise use 'username' and 'password'.

Note 2: you will need the following imports at the top of the script:

```
import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ConditionType
import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.TestObject as TestObject
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try without using the object WebUI. 
If you can share the entire code along with the error message in the console it would be great.